# GIT Ignore and GIT Hook - File is replaced after a commit-push

Tags: php, git, githooks

My GIT repository is located `/var/repo/myRepo.git`. I set a GIT hook `post-receive*` to copy the files from my repository to the folder of my project

`git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/myRepo.git checkout -f`

Each time I commit and push something on the server, the file `var/www/laravel/config/services.php` is replaced and the modification I did on the server is replaced by my local copy.

For instance, if I manually modify the following file like this **on the server** (by ssh session)

#### var/www/laravel/config/services.php

`This is the modified content of this file`

It will be like that after a commit and push

#### var/www/laravel/config/services.php

`This is the default content of this file`

I tried to add `/config/services.php` to my `.gitignore` but it does not seem to work.

#### .gitignore

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/public/hot
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
/config/services.php
```

What should I do so this file is not replaced each time I commit something on my server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `git rm /config/services.php` and reimported the file manually. Now the file is not replaced by GIT.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do so this file is not replaced each time I commit something on my server?

You have only two options:

1. don't check it in, or
2. don't check it out.

Your `git checkout -f` command means "get me the latest commit, overwriting everything."  If the latest commit has a new version of a file, that overwrites the old version of the file.

(Moreover, a `.gitignore` file does not mean what you think it means.  It's not a list of files to *ignore*.  It's a list of files—or name patterns—*not to complain about*.  Usually most important, it lets you declare to Git: "Yes, I know these are in my work-tree and not in my index; don't tell me that."  That's on the input side—i.e., the "don't check it in" part.)

This leads to a general rule about configurable software, where the software itself is maintained in Git, or indeed any version control system: **Do not put the configuration into the version control system.**  The *configuration* is not part of the software.

Consider Git itself, for instance.  You must *configure* Git to tell it your `user.name` and `user.email` in order to make commits with your user-name and email address.  Now imagine Git came with its configuration file built into the software, that said your user name is Fred and your email is `fred@fred.fred`.  *Every time you updated Git to a new version,* it would change your name back to "Fred <fred@fred.fred>".  That's not very friendly, is it?

Git stores your configuration *outside* of the Git software.  There are, to be sure, *default* configuration entries, but anything *you* set, is kept elsewhere.  Updating Git does not touch this.  This is not specific to Git, or even version-control systems: *any* system that provides upgrades *must not* store its configuration in a file that is destroyed by the upgrade.

So, stop doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it makes perfect sense. However I have to say I'm still a bit confused about the way to apply what you said ? I mean concretely what should I change in GIT or in the structure of my Laravel projet ?

Comment: I know nothing about Laravel, but the usual php answer is to read two config files, `configuration.php` and `config.local.php` for instance. Then you never add `config.local.php` to Git at all. In this case, whatever code reads `services.php` should read that and/or `services.local.php` if the latter exists (it's up to you to decide whether those are "overrides" or "entire config").